# Trying to have my discord bot add roles from a reaction to a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message

I'm having an issue where my bot wont give the respected role when a user reacts to the message correctly

```
    @client.event 
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    
        # Get the user who added the reaction
        guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        reacting_user = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    
        # Get the message object for the reaction
        channel = guild.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        
        # MESSAGE_ID defined in config file
        if message == MESSAGE_ID:
    
            if str(payload.emoji) == '':
                role = discord.utils.get(reacting_user.guild.roles, id=1056801648355324034)
                await reacting_user.add_roles(role)
    
            elif str(payload.emoji) == '':
                role = discord.utils.get(reacting_user.guild.roles, id=1056801755670777946)
                await reacting_user.add_roles(role)
```

I've tried using on_raw_reaction_add but I've have no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if condition is badly structured here. Check if `payload.message_id == 1234`

```
 if payload.message_id == 1234567:
     #stuffs
```

Also make sure that your intents are on.

Other issue could be the type conversation of MESSAGE_ID that you are pulling from `config.ini` (im guessing)
try doing:

```
if payload.message_id == int(MESSAGE_ID):
```

Comment: The intents im using are as follows
`intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True`

I changed my code to `if payload.message_id == MESSAGE_ID:` but its still not working

Comment: Your code worked fine for me when I fixed the if condition. 
If it is not throwing any error then the error should be in if condition. Are you sure your message id is correct in your config file?

also make sure you are passing `intents=intents` in your bot constructor

Comment: yeah I triple checked the config & made sure im calling from the config correctly as my token in is also called from the config and that works fine

Comment: Anyway we can get on discord or something so i can stream what I've got?

Comment: uh sure, what's your discord?

Comment: this is my constructor, I've got it as client not as bot `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)`